# Why do we need four steps to send our local changes to the central repository in GIT?

Tags: git, repository, commit

As far as I understood from [this git tutorial](http://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorial) we need to perform four steps to make changes to the central repository:

1. Edit files in the local repository.
2. Use `git add` to add a part of these changes to the `staging area`.
3. Use `git commit` to add the staging area to the `local project history`.
4. Use `got push` to upload the local changes to the central repository.

Theoretically we might want to do it in two steps:

1. Edit files.
2. Submit changes to the central repository.

And I understand why it might be not optimal. The two-steps-approach does not allow us to split the local changes in different logical groups. We might want to submit different changes separately using different comments. So, this is why we use `git add` to put a group (or part) of changes to the `staging area`. But then we have three (not four) steps.

So, in fact, I do not understand why in addition to `git commit` we need `git push`. Why do we want to have two steps instead of one?

Comment: Why are you trying to use Git when you want to use SVN (or any other centralized VCS)?

Comment: Because git is __decentralized__ version control system. You can use scripts/aliases to achieve the two-step process you might want.

Comment: @Nevik Rehnel, I do not want to use SVN, I want to use Git and want to understand it.

Comment: @user1615903, I do not really need the two stage process. I just want to understand why we might want to have four stage process.

Comment: You might be interested in reading the insight on the role of "central" Git repositories [given by Linus Torvalds to KDE folks](http://lwn.net/Articles/246381/) (Linus is the principal Git author).

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is that you appear to look at Git at a wrong angle: *local* history is crucial for Git model; remote repositories may or may not be used, and any local repository might communicate with any number of remote repositories, in different ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you question correctly, you are wondering why local commits are not automatically pushed to a remote repository. There are many reasons for that, for example:

- Developers might want to keep a feature that is under development strictly to themselves, and then squash their local commits into one/otherwise refactor the commit history before pushing to a remote for others to see
- You might have forked someone else's repository but do not want to contribute to that repository, but just occasionally pull the latest changes from upstream, keeping your local changes to yourself
- You might want to work offline and still make occasional commits, for example when travelling

The essential part is, Git is **decentralized** (or distributed) version control.

Comment: I understand the idea of squashing many changes into one very well (it totally makes sense to me). However, I do not understand why this cannot achieved with `git add`. You can add many changes to one staging area and then send it at once to one of the external repositories. The same is valid for working off line. Why it is not sufficient to add changes to the stage, when you off line, and then, when you on line, send them to one of the repositories.

Comment: I think that's because it's considered good practise that each commit presents a single change/bugfix/feature. So that undoing a specific change is easy with git revert for example.